# How to fix navigation component dependence ERROR?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation, dependencies

When I sync, nothing is happen. But I run my app, having an error. This is my build.gradle(app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.newsapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.newsapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.2")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.2")
}
```

And this is my build.gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

When I run app, have this error:

8 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.7.2' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the Android APIs.
   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 7.4.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
2. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.7.2' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 7.4.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
3. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.7.2' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 7.4.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
4. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.7.2' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 7.4.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
5. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.2' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 7.4.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
6. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.2' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 7.4.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
7. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.2' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 7.4.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
8. Dependency 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.2' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 7.4.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
   How to fix this error? Thanks.

I want to fix this problem, I tried fix this but nothing is happen.

Comment: So did you try updating your `compileSdk` to 34?

Answer (score 0):

I had this mistake before when default colors (res/values/colors.xml) were replaced by me in android studio project. I worked with template Navigation Drawer Views Activity on the startup screen. By adding default colors into res/values/colors.xml I solved this problem

```
<color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
<color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
<color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
<color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
<color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
```